# How to solve this tensorial equation $ g_{ij} x^ix^j =0$

Tags: matrices, differential-geometry, tensors

How to solve this tensorial equation $ g_{ij} x^ix^j=0$ , Einstein notation for summation is used.

$ i, j  \in \{1,2,3,4\} , x=\{x^1, x^2, x^3, x^4\} $

Given $ g_{ij} $ is a non singular $ 4$ x $4$ matrix, and symmetric $ g_{ij} =g_{ji} $ How to find non trivial solutions $ x \neq 0$?

Comment : I know how to solve this $g_{ij} y^i_ny^j_k=\delta^n_k $ but I can't see how that helps.

Comment: So, in matrix form, $x^TAx=0$.

Comment: @runway44 yeah that's correct

Comment: What else do you know about $g_{ij}$? Is it positive-definite? Do you have particular numbers, say?

Comment: @TedShifrin  it is symmetric $ g_{ij} =g_{ji} $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you intend each $g_{ij},\,x^i$ to be real. Then, since $g$ is symmetric, diagonalizing it obtains a matrix with real diagonal entries. We're given that none of these are zero, and if they're all positive the only solution is $x=0$. But if some eigenvalues are positive and others are negative, nontrivial solutions exist. A similarity transformation can set each eigenvalue of $g$ to be $\pm 1$ with the $+1$s grouped together, so we can rewrite the problem as $x_\uparrow^2=x_\downarrow^2$ (say).